# Class vs Interface in Patch org

Tags: managed-package, class, interface, patchorg

Why am I able to change the access specifier for an interface in a patch org but I can't do the same for a class?

I know the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_patches_creating.htm) mentions some restrictions for patch orgs.

I'm assuming the answer is very simple like 'interface isn't a class' or, is the answer a bit more complex?